# Apply and repeat formula for specific cell values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

There are 2 columns in an excel (CUST and VAL). I want to have OP column which will contain the addition of current col VAL + previous column VAL and this will continue per CUST. For new CUST the calculation will start again from 2nd row of that specific CUST where the 1st row will be empty for all CUST always.
The below image describes the same.

[image]

Comment: This is a combination of `IF()` and `COUNTIF()` but what is it you have tried?

Comment: I'm not that pro in excel, but what i am thinking is we need to apply some kind of window function for CUST and provide a same index reference. i.e. all 'aaa' CUST will have Index = 1, 'bbb' will have Index =2 like that. Now the formula to add previous VAL+current VAL will continue within same Index reference. When the Index reference will change the calculation will start from begining. Not sure how to do it in Excel

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this done by using the below formula
=IF(A3=A2,B3+B2,"")